# How to update a django_bootstrap_datepicker_plus date field with JS

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using django_bootstrap_datepicker_plus as a widget for my date fields. I'm developing a JavaScript to update a "due" date when an "issuance" date is filled by the user. I am able to reach the input field and to update it, and it is displayed to the user. Unfortunately, this new value is not part of the request.POST, it still has the former value.
I know that datepicker triggers a "dp.change" event when the user uses the widget to choose a date in the calendar. I've tried to trigger this event after updating the field, but it does not work.
Has anyone a hint ?
Thanks
Richard